# in Golang, what's the different between `array[:]` and `[]slice{array[0],array[1],...}` ？

Tags: arrays, algorithm, go, slice

I'd love to know why, please give me a little hint.

I want to append an array into `res`, the `res` is a Two-dimensional slice. So I need convert first.
When I convert an array into a slice, there is a bug.

```golang
// I need a map to remove duplicates
mm := map[[3]int]bool{}
mm[[3]int{-1, -1, 2}] = true
mm[[3]int{-1, -1, 2}] = true
mm[[3]int{-1, 0, 1}] = true

var res [][]int
for k, _ := range mm {
    res = append(res, k[:])
}
fmt.Printf("the res is %v\n", res)
```

```bash
the res is [[-1 0 1] [-1 0 1]]
```

But the result is not what I want.

then I tentatively modified the for loop a bit

```golang
for k, _ := range mm {
    //res = append(res, k[:])
    res = append(res, []int{k[0], k[1], k[2]})
}
```

```bash
the res is [[-1 0 1] [-1 -1 2]]
```

now the result is right, but why?
What's the different between `k[:]` and `[]int{k[0],k[1],k[2]}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the loop to

```
for k, _ := range mm {
    j := k
    res = append(res, j[:])
}
```

Your original loop declares a variable `k` of type `[3]int`, which has a particular location in memory. Every iteration of the loop, a different key from map `mm` is copied to that variable. So far, so good.

When you convert it to a slice using `k[:]`, it creates a slice header that *points* to the array `k`. It goes wrong here - the next iteration of the loop, the value of `k` gets overwritten. All slices created in the loop point to the same backing array `k` at the same location in memory.

By copying the value of `k` first to a variable that was declared *inside* the loop, you give each slice its own backing array, and you avoid the problem.

Answer (score 2):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec)
>
> [For statements](https://go.dev/ref/spec#For_statements)
>
> For statements with range clause
>
> The iteration variables may be declared by the "range" clause using a form of short variable declaration (:=). In this case their types are set to the types of the respective iteration values and their scope is the block of the "for" statement; they are re-used in each iteration.

Adding the `k := k` statement shadows the re-used iteration variable `k` with a local variable `k` for each iteration.

package main

```
import "fmt"

func main() {
    mm := map[[3]int]bool{}
    mm[[3]int{-1, -1, 2}] = true
    mm[[3]int{-1, -1, 2}] = true
    mm[[3]int{-1, 0, 1}] = true
    fmt.Println(mm)

    var res [][]int
    for k, _ := range mm {
        k := k
        res = append(res, k[:])
    }
    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/4BdXzdThxXd

```
map[[-1 -1 2]:true [-1 0 1]:true]
[[-1 -1 2] [-1 0 1]]
```